# How does tsc get its definitions when using npm definitions

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, tsc

So I settled from using `typings` to just using `npm`.
So you have the `@types` directory in `node_modules`, but besides that, there are no additional files.

With `typings` I always had to include the `index.d.ts` file in `typings`, but using `npm` this is not necessary. I want to ask why this is the case.

Does `npm` use some kind of hidden feature of `tsc` or did Microsoft and the people behind `npm` agree to something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `tsc` automatically checks `./node_modules/@types`. [Take a look](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types):

> By default all visible “@types” packages are included in your
>   compilation. Packages in node_modules/@types of any enclosing folder
>   are considered visible; specifically, that means packages within
>   ./node_modules/@types/, ../node_modules/@types/,
>   ../../node_modules/@types/, and so on.